# C++ Program E0079 expected a type specifier

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I have an c++ example project from an USB 3.0 Interface vendor called streamer application from cypress fx3. I wanted to get this to run first and see the potential behind the application but unfornately I'm getting a whole set of errors when building in Visual Studio 2017.

I get errors in the main file streamer.cpp showing me the errors:

> Error (active) E0079   expected a type specifier Line 26
>   Error (active) E1986   an ordinary pointer to a C++/CLI ref class or interface >class is not allowed Line 28

in Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

// windows.h includes WINGDI.h which
// defines GetObject as GetObjectA, breaking
// System::Resources::ResourceManager::GetObject.
// So, we undef here.
#undef GetObject

#include "Streamer.h"

#undef MessageBox

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;  
using namespace Streams;

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                   int       nCmdShow)
{
System::Threading::Thread::CurrentThread->ApartmentState = 
System::Threading::ApartmentState::STA;

try
{
    Application::Run(new Form1());   // THIS IS LINE 26
}
catch (Exception *e)  // THIS IS LINE 28
{
    MessageBox::Show(e->StackTrace,e->Message);
}

return 0;
}
```

Form 1 is part of streamer.h . In streamer h the error amount exceedes 400.
Most often compiler tells me identifier expected (E0040) even for syntax like private and public. Then the "this" operator causes an error:

> Error (active) E0258   'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member >function

What I tried to get this running:
- Installing missing windows sdk version 8.1 via installation routine in windows system control
- Changing Common Language Runtime Support to /clr
- inluding all missing header-files, compiler is now finding these header files.

Seems to me that there is something missing in the source project. Can you push me in the right direction?

Comment: This is C++/CLI, **not** C++. Don't tag unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception *e)
```

That is an unmanaged exception. You need to catch a *managed* exception:

```
catch (Exception^ e)
```